# It doesn't print the increased value of a variable in the for loop of batch file

Tags: batch-file

As you can see I am new in the batch files, I have written a script in windows 2003 environment for print an increased value of the variable counter and also I have applied the if condition which is not working in the for loop, though outside the for it is showing the correct number of variable value.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set /A counter = 1
for C:\Scripts\LogFiles\  %%a in (*.txt) do ( echo %counter%
set /A counter += 1
echo %%a
if %counter% ==2 (echo test)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delayed expansion requires you to use `!` instead of `%` to expand variables. So it should be `!counter!`.

All environment variables of the form `%counter%` are expanded during *parsing* of a command (for `for` with a block this includes the complete block), so you'll only see the value a variable had *before* the loop since by the time the loop runs there are no variables anymore; only values.